# Generate 2^N-1 number of matrices from a MXN matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix

I need to generate all possible combinations of a `10X5 matrix`. What I need is all `10X1 matrix`, `10X2 matrix`, `10X3 matrix` etc. What' the most efficient way. i can use multiple loops but that would be inefficient.
eg: I have a  matrix:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
```

I want:

```
col1 and col2 and col3 and col4
```

then:

`col1 col2 and col1 col3 and col1 col4`

and so on to return all 2^5-1 combinations of **columns**

Comment: Combination of columns, of rows or both? A short example, say 4 by 3, would help.

Comment: Your question critically lacks information. Do you just want a matrix with the first column, one with the first and second, etc? Or do you want to have all possible permutations of values within rows?

Comment: @OlegKomarov I have edited question.Sorry about the mistake in question earlier.

Comment: col5 col3 is also possible solution?

Comment: @0x90 No.Total combinations will be 2^5-1 and hence col5-col3 will be a repition of col3-col5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `nchoosek` in a loop:

```
for k = 1:ceil(5/2) %only need to go half way up otherwise start repeating
  index{k} = nchoosek(1:5, k);
end
```

and then use index to get the submatrices by selecting columns

Comment: Thanks a lot.Amazed by how simple everything is in matlab :) Thanks for awesome answer.

Answer (score 2):

I won't going to solve it for you but here are some useful functions. You must clarify what exactly is your input.

```
>> nchoosek([1:4],3)

ans =

     1     2     3
     1     2     4
     1     3     4
     2     3     4

>> combntns([1:3],2)

ans =

     1     2
     1     3
     2     3

>> perms([1:3])

ans =

     3     2     1
     3     1     2
     2     3     1
     2     1     3
     1     2     3
     1     3     2
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. I can use these in fututre. Thanks a lot. First function did the job